# Excel Vba Sort Date in MMM format

Tags: sorting, date, excel, vba

I have some columns of dates in the format of `MMM-DD-YYYY` for example `Jan-03-2014` but when I sort it using:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Z" & rowNum).Sort Key1:=ActiveSheet.Columns("E")
```

It doesn't sort by real date. I realized its treating it like strings and sorting them based on first letter. Is there anyway to sort it by real date?

Thanks

Comment: Just tried this and it sorted for me by date... Are your dates now text or are they still numerical (eg: Is Jan 1, 2013 = 41275)?

Comment: my dates now are still text(eg: Dec-25-2013), I did Int(CDbl(CDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 6).Value))) where cells(3,6).value is Jan-01-2013 and it is equal to 41275 but I don't think my workbook is recognizing Jan-01-2013 as a date

Comment: Since they are still text, you are correct, it won't recognize them as dates. Your best / easiest bet would be to create a new (helper) column that's simply `=DATEVALUE(other column)` then sort based upon that one...

Comment: Thanks! I made another column and sorted it based on that column. Now everything works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on suggestions from John, to sort dates in MMM format I would need to create a new column, make it a date and sort it based on that column, I used the code below:

```
For i = 3 To rowNum
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value = CDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value)
    End If
Next i
ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Z" & rowNum).sort Key1:=ActiveSheet.Columns("H"), Header:=xlNo
ActiveSheet.Columns("H").Delete
```

Just thought I should share it, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by recording a macro in Excel, it give me something like that and sort dates in the format of "MMM-DD-YYYY"

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:C1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "janvier,février,mars,avril,mai,juin,juillet,août,septembre,octobre,novembre,décemb         re" _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C1")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: I modified it a bit into:
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3:Z100"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec" _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal

But it says object does not support this method :(

Comment: i think you need to put the full name of month to make this work : "january,february...." And can't you use the option "record macro" from excel? it will generate code, exactly for what you want, you just need to adapt range after